# How do I ask a question from Emacs sx.el?

Tags: sx.el

I'm trying to use `sx.el`.

So far I can read and move around, but when I try to ask a question pressing `a`, I end up in the `sx draft question emacs` buffer showing:

```
Title: \
Tags:
```

but there I can't type anything and get the message: `Text is read-only`

How do I ask a question from Emacs `sx.el`? I'm asking this through my browser.

edit: i can edit this post though from emacs.

Comment: It's a [bug](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/issues/341) that's been around for some years. Sadly `sx.el` does not seem to be maintained.

Comment: @NickD thx! i tried the solution in the link you gave, replacing the `read only t` to `read only nil` and now i can type in the buffer, but when i try to send to SE, i get `sx-request-make: Request failed: (nil) [400 bad_parameter] "body"` error.

Comment: That confirms my hunch that it is not maintained any longer.